# How can I use find with each element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, each

I want to get all table elements then search for elements in each table.

```
  var tbody = $('table')
  tbody.each(function(table) {
      var elementsArray = table.find('sometext"'); // doesn't work

  })
```

Here it says

> Uncaught TypeError: table.find is not a function

How can I use `find` like this?

Comment: `table` should be `$(table)`

Comment: Since `table` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.find is a jquery method so you have to use it for a jquery selector like `$(selector).find` and also you have a syntax error in `.find('sometext"')` you have to change it like `.find('sometext')`

```
var tbody = $('table')
  tbody.each(function(index, table) {
      var elementsArray = $(table).find('sometext'); // should work

  })
```